# Firebase authentication in html

Tags: html, firebase, authentication, web, firebase-authentication

Hey do I need to initialize firebase in every html page that I use it in? If not, how do I re-use all the config and initialization done in one html file in all the others that will require firebase to be used?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialize it with the config to get the `firebase` object, so without setting up the config you will not get to use the object. A common practice is to just write a script file with the initialization code, for example `config.js` and add the script to all necessary html pages. Be careful to do all firebase-y stuff after the configuration is done.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will try it out.